# изминение языка ответов в iis

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10

установил русскую windows 10,
поставил VS-15 (en) 
при использовании iis express (от вижуал студии) ответы английские (в том числе ошибки), а вот при использовании local iis ответы и exception'ы  русские
пробывал изменить globalization, так же установил язык интерфейса английский все равно не помогает, есть ли способ изменить язык ответов в local iis? искал на англ stackoverflow все что предлагали делал, не помогло 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример "ошибки" о которой я говорю

upd
при использовании IIS express я получаю "нужную ошибку" на английском
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавить в web.config

   ```
   <system.web>
      <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
   </system.web>
   ```
2. Убедиться что в global.asax нет замены локали
3. Задать региональные настройки для аккаунта под которым работает сервер
4. Удалить поддержку языка из ОС и дотнета :))

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил `<globalization uiCulture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />`. Скорее всего и в IE стоит по умолчанию русский язык, и HTTP-header соответствующий серверу посылается.

Comment: суть в том что при переключении сайта на iis express включается англ язык, в local  IIS выставил globalization - en-US глобально для всех сайтов